# How can I display social icons on my website with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am desperately trying to add some icons to my website but can't get them appear properly. What I want is just a  container that contains images and display them in line. Then I would want to add some padding to that  container and in between the images and that's it.

See here my approach. If anyone can help me out and correct my code so that it actually works, I would be more than happy.

In my HTML file:

```
<div class="icons">
    <div class="email"><a href="mailto:example@hotmail.com" title="email"></a></div>
    <div class="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com" title="twitter">twitter</a>    
</div>
```

In my CSS:

```
.icons {
    margin-left:30px;
}

.icons .email { background: url(../images/social/email.png) left top no-repeat; }
.icons .twitter { background: url(../images/social/twitter.png) left top no-repeat; }
```

NOTE: This code did not work for me.

Comment: Add width and height properties on .email and .twitter classes. Also, use those classes inside anchor tag, not on div.

Comment: @Miljan Puzović, ok that worked for me. How can I display them inline?

Comment: @user1420042 as you are using `div` add `float:left;` to `.icons` class

Comment: It's bad to use empty elements, especially when you're trying to make something linkable. If these are not going to be rollovers, why are you using a background image rather than dropping in the actual image? That said, if you're determined to use `background-image`, your best off putting in a 1px transparent gif to use as the clickable image so the browser has something physical to render. Just include height and width attributes to your `img` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create an image sprite for my icons. And then for the markup I would use a list and set the icon images as background images to their respective anchor tags.

Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="" class="icon facebook">Facebook</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="icon twitter">Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="icon googleplus">Google Plus</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
float:left;
display:block;
}

.icon {
width:25px;
height:25px;
display:block;
text-indent:-9999px;
background-image:url(http://tridentdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/gemicon.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.facebook {
background-position:-140px -115px;
}
.twitter {
background-position:-185px -115px;
}
.googleplus {
background-position:-140px -265px;
}
```

**HERE IS A FIDDLE TO DEMONSTRATE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8zkK/2/

Comment: in your example, if i use an image sprite, wouldn't it be just one image. I mean, why do you have Facebook.png, twitter.png, googleplus.png if you use a sprite?

Comment: Good point sorry I messed that up. The image should actually be on the icon class. I will edit it quick.

Comment: just a last one: in the html change the class name to "facebook", "twitter", i.e remove "icon"

Comment: The icon class is necessary to set all of the base styling. The other three classes are only used to change the background position of the image sprite depending on what icon it is. I will create a fiddle.

Comment: Any particular reason why? I might be able to help.

Comment: the problem is that i have text on top of my images and the list circle show up.

Comment: how can i get my images show up i a line. right now they look like stairs (from left down to the right)

Comment: You will need to add some styles to remove the list circles. I usually use CSS reset to standardize everything. And to hide the text use text-indent:-9999px; or text-indent:-150%; or something along those lines.

Comment: I edited my example. Check out my fiddle link. To make them appear in a line you need to add CSS `float:left;` and `display:block;` styles for the `<li>`.

Comment: For reseting CSS check out this website. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: is it possible to add an id/class to that <ul>. It kinda works now but messes up another <ul> that I have. Can you add that in your example?

Comment: Yeah you can certainly add ID's and classes where ever you need them. I would recommend using a class though. That way you can reuse it. I just used it without a class or id because it was the only one in my example.

Comment: just a last question: Is it ok/ good practice to use <div> instead of <li>? That works perfect for me!

Comment: Using a list is more semantic and accessible. If you use `<div>` for `<li>` then you will also need to change the `<ul>` to a `<div>`. It isn't necessarily wrong. But in my opinion using a list is a better option / practice.

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding an image in CSS you should add atleast `Height` or `width`, it's good to add both, you can ignore(not necessarily) when you are adding images using `img` tag.

To get in  inline, as you are using `div`, add `float:left` to `.icons` class

```
 .icons {
  margin-left:30px;
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  }
```

You can also use the answer by `Kris Hollenbeck`, in that case you have to rewrite you HTML code too, which is highly preferred.