# How can I add a hover effect to icons with CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover, effects

I am updating my website and used this article [How can I display social icons on my website with HTML and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645634/how-can-i-display-social-icons-on-my-website-with-html-and-css) to add some social media icons to my website.

Now I am wondering, how can I achieve a hover effect, i.e. change opacity). I know this should be only a few lines of code but I have no idea how to achieve that (CSS beginner)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this (CSS) if you want to target the specific element with class `.email`:

```
.icons .email:hover {
    // Your code here
    opacity: .5;
}
```

If you want a more generic solution, give all elements the samen class (`.icon` in this example) and do:

```
.icons:hover {
    // Your code here
    opacity: .5;
}
```

You might want to read about CSS [cascading and inheritence](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html).

Comment: thanks, but is there a more general approach. I don't really like the idea of adding this code for every icon

Comment: @user1420042 You're not adding any code for every icon.  Just give all of the icons a class of `icons` and your `.icons` CSS rules will be applied to all of the elements with that class.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I've edited my comment to reflect another approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by following code:

```
.className:hover (or) #id:hover{
opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div:hover{ do: something }
```

Find out more about [css selectors here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need opacity for this, you can just aswell use the display attribute. This will work for all labels with an image with the class icon inside.

I added the blue background as a stand in for an image.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7uLbF/3/)

**Html:**

```
<label class="labelWithIcon"><img class="icon" />test</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
.labelWithIcon .icon{
    display:none;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.labelWithIcon:hover .icon{
    display:inline;
}

.labelWithIcon{
    padding-left:10px;
}

.labelWithIcon:hover{
     padding-left:0px;   
}
```

**EDIT:** Made the selector more specific than "label"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:hover` pseudo-class:

```
.social:hover{opacity: .7;}
```